# Is the XOR-combiner of independent keyed hash-functions collision resistant?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, xor

Assume there are two keyed hash-functions $H_1(k_1, m)$ and $H_2(k_2, m)$, with $k_1$ and $k_2$ being independently randomly sampled public keys.

The XOR-combiner is defined as $C_\oplus^{H_1, H_2}:=H_1(k_1, m) \oplus H_2 (k_2, m)$.

Assuming at least one of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is collision resistant, is $C_\oplus^{H_1, H_2}$, as defined above, necessarily collision-resistant for any combination of $H_1, H_2$?

[Mittelbach (2014)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/210.pdf) says: "The exclusive-or combiner is also not robust for collision resistance, even assuming independent functions, as a collision on the combiner does not require collisions under both input functions.", but he's talking about Hash-functions without keys. He also does not provide a proof or counterexample which I could attempt to apply for this problem.

Here's my approach which unfortunately did not lead anywhere:

When attempting a reduction proof, I realized that if an adversary $A$ finds a collision against $C_\oplus^{H_1, H_2}$, that means that $H_1(k_1, m_0)\oplus H_2(k_2,m_0)=H_1(k_1, m_1)\oplus H_2(k_2,m_1)$. However, as Mittelbach (2014) stated, this does not necessarily imply that $H_1(k_1, m_0)=H_1(k_1, m_1)$ or $H_2(k_1, m_0)=H_2(k_1, m_1)$, because it is possible that $H_1(k_1, m_0)\oplus H_1(k_1, m_1)=H_2(k_2, m_0)\oplus H_2(k_2, m_1) \neq 0$.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a counterexample for $H_1, H_2$ for which I could construct an adversary that breaks collision resistance, leaving me stuck in both attempts of proving and disproving the collision-resistance of $C_\oplus^{H_1, H_2}$.

Comment: What is the origin of this question? The answer is not simple see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-019-09328-w

Comment: @kelalaka It's an exercise for an introductary cryptography course... I'll have a look at the article you linked, thank you!

Comment: If $H_k$ is collision resistant, then $H'_k(x\Vert b) = H_k(x)\Vert b$ is also collision resistant. (left as an exercise to the reader) What happens if you instantiate both hash functions with $H'$?

Comment: I'm assuming $b$ refers to a single bit? Then $C_\oplus^{H_1', H_2'}=H_1(k_1, m)\|b\oplus H_2(k_2, m)\|b=(H_1(k_1, m)\oplus H_2(k_2, m))\|(b\oplus b)=(H_1(k_1, m)\oplus H_2(k_2, m))\|0$. How would you construct an adversary against this without solving the original problem?

Comment: Doesn't really matter if it's a single bit or not, but yes that was the intention. Have you noticed how the hash value is suddenly independent of $b$?

Comment: True, but isn't it still dependent on $m$? Meaning the adversary still has to find a value for $m_0, m_1$ in order to find a collision? I see that it's not pseudorandom, but collision resistance does not imply pseudorandomness, afaik.

Comment: Well, are $m\Vert 0$ and $m\Vert 1$ for some fixed $m$ the same message? Do they have the same hash value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150647/discussion-between-kristian-koenig-and-maeher).